# Retrieve a variable out of a function in a javascript loop

Tags: javascript, function, variables, loops

I am having trouble with the following script:
  When a user clicks on an upload button and selects some images it creates `divs` and add one per image.

However I cannot manage to retrieve the `tba` variable out of its function. I know this question has been asked several times already and I tried many different approaches (including the `reader.onload` in a function...) however I did not manage to successfully retrieve that variable.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function() {
     function readURL(input) {      
        if (input.files) {
            var tba = '';
            for (var i = 0; i < input.files.length; i++) {
                if(input.files[i]) {

                    var reader = new FileReader();

                    reader.onload = function (e) {
                            tba += '<div class="gallery_image"><img src="'+e.target.result+'" alt="Image currently not accessible" /></div>';
                    };

                    reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[i]);
                }
            }

            $('#gallery_container').html(tba);
        }
    } 
 });
</script>
```

Thank you very much for your help, have a nice day.

Comment: you're trying to solve the wrong problem. don't try to get the variable "out of the function". instead, use it within the function.

Comment: you can't retrieve the `tba` at this point `$('#gallery_container').html(tba);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The variable `tba` in just available inside your function scope. To access `tba` outside of this function, move the declaration outside of it too.

```
  // global
     var tba = '';

     $(document).ready(function() { 
         function readURL(input) {      
            if (input.files) {
                tba = '';
```

EDIT:

Since the first part of my answer didn't provide the desired help, how about dropping `tba` and do the DOM manipulating directly?

Your function should look like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function() {
     function readURL(input) {      
        if (input.files) {
            $('#gallery_container').html(''); //clear the container
            for (var i = 0; i < input.files.length; i++) {
                if(input.files[i]) {

                    var reader = new FileReader();

                    reader.onload = function (e) {
                        // append your generated HTML directly
                        $('#gallery_container').append('<div class="gallery_image"><img src="'+e.target.result+'" alt="Image currently not accessible" /></div>');
                    };

                    reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[i]);
                }
            }
            // removed the dom manipulating part here
        }
    } 
 });
</script>
```

Comment: Sorry I guess my question is not precise enough. The problem is that I cannot retrieve tba out of reader.onload = function (e). The concatenation works but I cannot access the final value out of this function.

Comment: Since `tba`was not global from the beginning, try my example and report if it is still not working.

Comment: Please have a look at my edit. I hope this will solve your problem.

Comment: Actually that's exactly what I came up with, thank you for your efforts!

Answer (score 0):

If you define the variable outside the function it will get the value from the function. 
That is called global scope, otherwise it's only available inside the function scope.

Check this:

```
var a = 30;

function foo() {
    a = 25;
}
foo();
alert(a); // will give 25
```

Check live **[here](http://jsfiddle.net/Z6FZc/)**

So your code should look like:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function() {
     var tba = '';
     function readURL(input) {      
        if (input.files) {
            for (var i = 0; i < input.files.length; i++) {
                if(input.files[i]) {

                    var reader = new FileReader();

                    reader.onload = function (e) {
                            tba += '<div class="gallery_image"><img src="'+e.target.result+'" alt="Image currently not accessible" /></div>';
                    };

                    reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[i]);
                }
            }

            $('#gallery_container').html(tba);
        }
    } 
 });
</script>
```